# Actionscript 2.0 if and else functions not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am using this script on my button:

```
   on(release){
var body2:Boolean = true; 
answerField = body2
var body1:Boolean = false;
var body3:Boolean = false; 

gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

And this script on my second button:

```
on (release) {
if (body1=true) {
   gotoAndStop(4);
} else if (body2=true) {
    gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
  gotoAndStop(6);  
}
}
```

However for some reason I can not get my second button to take me to frame 5 even when body2=true.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because simply you are using an assignment operator ( `=` ) instead of the comparison one ( `==` ) in your `if` statements which they can be :

```
if (body1 == true) {            // you can write it : if(body1){}
    gotoAndStop(4);
} else if (body2 == true) {     // you can write it : if(body2){}
    gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
    gotoAndStop(6);  
}
```

For more about ActionScript operators, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html).

Also, your `Boolean`s should be declared globally using [`_global`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000621.html) to be accessible everywhere in your code, or in your main timeline to be accessible using `_root.my_var`, and when they are declared inside a MovieClip or Button code, you can call them, for example, using `_root.my_button.myvar` ...

So in your case, supposed that your first button is called `button1`, the code of your other button can be like this :

```
if (_root.button1.body1) {  
    gotoAndStop(4);
} else if (_root.button1.body2) {
    gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
    gotoAndStop(6);  
}
```

**Edit :**

Example of using `_global` :

code on `button1` :

```
on (release) {
    _global.body2 = true;
    _global.body1 = false;
    _global.body3 = false;
}
```

code on `button2` :

```
on (release) {
    trace(body2);      // gives : true
    trace(body1);      // gives : false
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am having trouble figuring out how and where to declare my booleans globally? I have tried simply replacing var with _global. on my first button but that gives me errors.

Comment: What I am using:
on(release){
 _global.body1:Boolean = true; 
  var answerField = _global.body1
 _global.body2:Boolean = false;
 _global.body3:Boolean = false; 

gotoAndStop(1);
}

Comment: @Racetrack I added a little example of how to use `_global`, take a look.